# Referrer coming as blank for a click

Tags: javascript, referrer

Sorry for being a noob, But can anyone please help me to understand the different conditions when i can expect a referrer to be null\blank. I use `document.referrer` to get the referrer information.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of reasons why REFERER might be blank.

1. HTTP_REFERER is an environment variable given by the browser. Meaning users can remove it or even change it, if they so intend to.
2. Users accessing the link from a bookmark, history or by typing the link manually do not have a referer.
3. IE has also been known to remove the referer in situations revolving around javascript. Such as window.open, window.location and even setting target="_blank" in anchors or meta refresh.
4. Clicking an embedded link in a chat application, PDF/Word/Excel document, will also not
   set a referer.
5. Using AJAX, file_get_contents, fopen and other similar functions in other languages will probably not set a referer request.
6. cURL, fsockopen, applications that have browser-like components might not set a referer.

Answer (score 0):

If the user uses an anonymizing proxy or add-on, it may be set to remove Referer headers.

If you use `document.location.href = URL` to go to the new page, whether Referer is passed is browser-dependent.